# Extract street address from string with multiple delimiters and positions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, string-manipulation

Trying to pull just the Street addresses out of this data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(Places varchar(50));
INSERT foo(Places) VALUES
('MARKET @123 NORTH RD'),
('HARDWARE @600 Main RD ;W1'),
('MAIN AV / NORTH RD'),
('500 NORTH RD @LIBRARY'),
('500 ANYSTREET ; *** SIDEWALK****'),
('MARKET @123 NORTH RD'),
('700 ANYSTREET'),
('(088.12345,088.12345) ;75 SOUTH RD');
```

I've trying to do use CASE, SUBSTRING and (CHAR/PAT)INDEX... But I'm just not doing this correctly.

```
Select 
[Address] = CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%@[0-9]%' , Places) = 0 THEN     (SUBSTRING(Places, 0, CHARINDEX('@',Places)))
                WHEN PATINDEX('%@[a-z]%' , Places) = 0 THEN     (SUBSTRING(Places, CHARINDEX('@',Places) + 1, LEN(Places)))
                WHEN PATINDEX('%;[0-9]%' , Places) = 0 THEN (SUBSTRING(Places, CHARINDEX(';',Places) + 1, LEN(Places)))
                WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9]%' , Places) = 1 THEN (SUBSTRING(Places, 0, CHARINDEX(';',Places))) 
                WHEN PATINDEX('%/%' , Places) > 0 THEN Places END

From dbo.foo
```

What is the better way to grab that data? I've looked at string selects for finding email addresses, but seem to fall flat again when dealing with the ';'

TIA!

edit for desired output, table containing:

```
123 NORTH RD 
600 Main RD
MAIN AV / NORTH RD
500 NORTH RD 
500 ANYSTREET
123 NORTH RD 
700 ANYSTREET
7575 SOUTH RD
```

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: A table of just the street addresses: 123 NORTH RD, 600 Main RD, MAIN AV / NORTH RD, 500 NORTH RD, 500 ANYSTREET, 123 NORTH RD, 700 ANYSTREET,7575 SOUTH RD

Comment: You should edit your question to add that in. The formatting in comments stinks.

Comment: I hear ya. Added.

Comment: Regex would make short work of this I'm sure.  But I think even a more traditional Sql solution is possible.  It usually helps me when I put into English exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
;With cte as
(
Select 
    places,
    StartHere = 
        CASE 
            WHEN PATINDEX('%@[0-9]%', places) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%@[0-9]%', places) + 1     -- @ plus number, start here
            WHEN PATINDEX('%;[0-9]%', places) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%;[0-9]%', places) + 1     -- ; plus number, start here
            ELSE 0
        END
    ,EndHere = 
        CASE
            WHEN PATINDEX('%@[a-z]%', places) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%@[a-z]%', places)   -- @plus letter, stop here        
            WHEN PATINDEX('%@[0-9]%', places) > 0 AND PATINDEX('%;%', places) > 0 THEN  PATINDEX('%;%', places)  --@ plus number stop on semicolon if there
            WHEN PATINDEX('%;[0-9]%', places) = 0 AND PATINDEX('%;%', places) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%;%', places)   --no semi plus number, so stop on semicolon if there
            ELSE len(places) + 1
        END
FROM
    foo
)
    SELECT 
        places, 
        StartHere
        ,EndHere
        ,SUBSTRING(places, StartHere, EndHere - StartHere)
    FROM 
        cte
```

Comment: I'd add that I started with the concept of start and end and added each condition (not sure I added all possibilities, you might have to expand).  But some possibilities just fell to the else of start at zero and end at end.  I ended up needing only 5 conditions.

Comment: This concept works on my test data as a subquery pretty well. I'm messing up the join for the production somehow though, not quite sure where I'm going wrong. I will keep messing with it, thank you for the pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do that with T-SQL - RegEx is no match for the creativity of end users with a text field.

If you need to do it production-quality at scale, check out the [Melissa Data SSIS components](https://www.melissadata.com/data-quality-ssis/index.htm). (I have no relationship with that company at all - just heard excellent things about it from people who have to do this exact sort of thing for a living.)

Comment: I have no doubt this is a technically correct answer.... But at this time, I need to operate in T-SQL. As much as it doesn't look like it, the data in these fields is actually NOT free form enter. It arrives a few different ways, hence the formatting challenge. Maybe I should just take my best effort approach and make the case to move to an SSIS option when/if there are issues.

Comment: Sorry but Brent is right, RegEx is just not powerful enough to deal with the uncertainties.  If I were in your situation and I couldn't use anything other than T-SQL alone (SSIS is exactly what I'd normally use), then I'd probably use a combination of RegEx and also a "Control" table where I'd have common expected values.  Then I'd use something like SOUNDEX or DIFFERENCE between the control table and your data to try to get the best matches possible.